# Plot various 2D curves in 3D

Tags: plotting

I can embed a 2D curve `f00==0` in 3D space using

```
zval=0
f00 = -3 (\[Pi]^6/64 + (-x^6 - y^6)) // ExpandAll // FullSimplify
curve = ContourPlot[f00 == 0, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}];
XYcirc = Cases[Normal@curve, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity];
Zcirc = Table[zval, {i, Dimensions[XYcirc][[2]]}];
Xcirc = Flatten@XYcirc[[All, All, 1]];
Ycirc = Flatten@XYcirc[[All, All, 2]];
XYZcirc = Transpose[{Xcirc, Ycirc, Zcirc}];
g4 = ListLinePlot3D[XYZcirc, PlotStyle -> Directive[red, Opacity[0.65]], Mesh -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

where I have extracted $x,y$ coordinates from `f00==0` and set the $z$ coordinate to `z=zval`. Based on the answer to one of my recent [quesions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269401/plotting-the-intersection-between-two-surfaces), I can now generate disconnected curves. For instance, setting `f1==0` or `f2==0` with

```
f1 = -3 (x^6 + y^6 + z^6) + 5 (x^4 + y^4 + z^4) \[Pi]^2 -  5/9 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \[Pi]^4 + \[Pi]^6/81 /. {z -> zval}
f2 = -6 (x^5 + y^5 + z^5) \[Pi] + 20/9 (x^3 + y^3 + z^3) \[Pi]^3 -  2/27 (x + y + z) \[Pi]^5 /. {z -> zval}
```

gives multiple points.
To obtain the coordinates of these points, I have tried the script above for the `f1==0` and `f2==0` functions, but I get many errors such as

```
"Part 2 of {23} does not exist."
```

I have also tried to replace `Dimensions[XYcirc]` with `Dimensions[XYcirc[[1]]]`, but this also didn't help.

Do you have any suggestions on how to extract these points and plot them in a 3D plot?

Comment: Please show what you tried: `f1==0` gives some surfaces in 3D (not a list {x,y})

Comment: `f1=\[Pi]^6/81 - 5/9 \[Pi]^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 5 \[Pi]^2 (x^4 + y^4) - 
 3 (x^6 + y^6)` is a function of $(x,y)$ as I set `z=zval`. Then plot `curve = ContourPlot[f1 == 0, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]` and the rest follows from the first script above.

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[f1 == 0, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, z]}, 
 Mesh -> {{-.3, -.3, -.1, 0.1, .2, .3}}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 PlotRange -> All, ContourStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 Boxed -> False]`?

Comment: @Shasa Thank you, I got it.  `ContourPlot[f1 == 0,...]` gives two curves, that might cause the errors!

Comment: @Ulrich-Neumann Exactly! And I don't know how to extract data from these disconnected curves.

Comment: @cvgmat This is great and partially solves my problem! I also want to extract these points from the ContourPlot3D? Something like `Xcirc` and `Ycirc` above.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Shasa `Cases[Normal@curve, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity] ` gives a list of two(!)  curves, you have to pick them separately!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Could you give a hint on how to separate them?

Comment: @hasa `lists=Cases[Normal@curve, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]` . First list: `lists[[1]]`, ...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann By using `Dimensions[XYcirc[[1]]]` in my question, I also tried to get the correct dimension, but somehow it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a slightly simpler approach that works even when there is more than one contour, generated using your $f_1$ expression:

```
curvef1 = ContourPlot[f1 == 0, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}];
points3D = 
  Cases[Normal@curvef1, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity] /. 
     {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, y, zval};
ListLinePlot3D[
  points3D, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.65]], 
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: 3D contour with two curves]

Comment: Thanks! This script generates both coordinates and the final plot.

Answer (score 5):

Marco's answer would be the best thing to do in this particular case. An alternative that is sometimes done is to use the `MeshFunctions` option of `ContourPlot3D[]`:

```
With[{zval = 0}, 
     {ContourPlot3D[-3 (x^6 + y^6 + z^6) + 5 (x^4 + y^4 + z^4) π^2 -
                    5/9 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) π^4 + π^6/81 == 0,
                    {x, -π, π}, {y, -π, π}, {z, -1, 1}, 
                    BoundaryStyle -> None, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
                    ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{zval}}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
                    MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.65]], PlotPoints -> 25], 
      ContourPlot3D[-6 (x^5 + y^5 + z^5) π + 20/9 (x^3 + y^3 + z^3) π^3 -
                    2/27 (x + y + z) π^5 == 0,
                    {x, -π, π}, {y, -π, π}, {z, -1, 1}, 
                    BoundaryStyle -> None, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
                    ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{zval}}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
                    MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.65]], PlotPoints -> 25]} //
      GraphicsRow]
```

[image: contours]

Comment: (+1) Thank you for sharing an alternative answer.

Comment: A similar answer has been suggested by @cvgmt in the comments above.