# Plotting regions with zero eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: plotting, eigenvalues

I have a series of matrices exemplify as

\begin{align}
Atmp=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 0. & 0. & 1.\, +0.5 e^{-i z} & 0. & 1. y+0.2 & 0.\, +0.75 i & 0. & 0. \\
 0. & 0. & 0. & -1.-0.5 e^{-i z} & 0.\, +0.75 i & 1. y-0.2 & 0. & 0. \\
 1.\, +0.5 e^{i z} & 0. & 0. & 0. & 0. & 0. & 0.2\, -1. y & 0.\, -0.75 i \\
 0. & -1.-0.5 e^{i z} & 0. & 0. & 0. & 0. & 0.\, -0.75 i & -1. y-0.2 \\
 1. y+0.2 & 0.\, -0.75 i & 0. & 0. & 0. & 0. & 1.\, +0.5 e^{-i z} & 0. \\
 0.\, -0.75 i & 1. y-0.2 & 0. & 0. & 0. & 0. & 0. & -1.-0.5 e^{-i z} \\
 0. & 0. & 0.2\, -1. y & 0.\, +0.75 i & 1.\, +0.5 e^{i z} & 0. & 0. & 0. \\
 0. & 0. & 0.\, +0.75 i & -1. y-0.2 & 0. & -1.-0.5 e^{i z} & 0. & 0. \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}

which can be added to the Mathematica using

```
Atmp = {{0., 0., 1. + 0.5 E^(-I z), 0., 0.2 + 1. y, 0. + 0.75 I, 0., 
    0.}, {0., 0., 0., -1. - 0.5 E^(-I z), 0. + 0.75 I, -0.2 + 1. y, 
    0., 0.}, {1. + 0.5 E^(I z), 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.2 - 1. y, 
    0. - 0.75 I}, {0., -1. - 0.5 E^(I z), 0., 0., 0., 0., 
    0. - 0.75 I, -0.2 - 1. y}, {0.2 + 1. y, 0. - 0.75 I, 0., 0., 0., 
    0., 1. + 0.5 E^(-I z), 0.}, {0. - 0.75 I, -0.2 + 1. y, 0., 0., 0.,
     0., 0., -1. - 0.5 E^(-I z)}, {0., 0., 0.2 - 1. y, 0. + 0.75 I, 
    1. + 0.5 E^(I z), 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0. + 0.75 I, -0.2 - 1. y, 
    0., -1. - 0.5 E^(I z), 0., 0.}};
```

Here is the plot of all eigenvalues.[image]. The figure can be generated using

```
L=30;
r1 = Table[{y, z, 
    Re[Sort[Chop[Eigenvalues[Atmp]]][[1]]]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 
    Pi/L}, {z, -Pi + 0.01, Pi, Pi/L}];
r2 = Table[{y, z, 
    Re[Sort[Chop[Eigenvalues[Atmp]]][[2]]]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 
    Pi/L}, {z, -Pi + 0.01, Pi, Pi/L}];
r3 = Table[{y, z, 
    Re[Sort[Chop[Eigenvalues[Atmp]]][[3]]]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 
    Pi/L}, {z, -Pi + 0.01, Pi, Pi/L}];
r4 = Table[{y, z, 
    Re[Sort[Chop[Eigenvalues[Atmp]]][[4]]]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 
    Pi/L}, {z, -Pi + 0.01, Pi, Pi/L}];
r5 = Table[{y, z, 
    Re[Sort[Chop[Eigenvalues[Atmp]]][[5]]]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 
    Pi/L}, {z, -Pi + 0.01, Pi, Pi/L}];
r6 = Table[{y, z, 
    Re[Sort[Chop[Eigenvalues[Atmp]]][[6]]]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 
    Pi/L}, {z, -Pi + 0.01, Pi, Pi/L}];
r7 = Table[{y, z, 
    Re[Sort[Chop[Eigenvalues[Atmp]]][[7]]]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 
    Pi/L}, {z, -Pi + 0.01, Pi, Pi/L}];
r8 = Table[{y, z, 
    Re[Sort[Chop[Eigenvalues[Atmp]]][[8]]]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 
    Pi/L}, {z, -Pi + 0.01, Pi, Pi/L}];


g1 = ListPlot3D[Flatten[r1, 1], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[blue, Opacity[0.65]], Mesh -> False, 
   PlotRange -> All];
g2 = ListPlot3D[Flatten[r2, 1], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[orange, Opacity[0.65]], Mesh -> False, 
   PlotRange -> All];
g3 = ListPlot3D[Flatten[r3, 1], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.65]], Mesh -> False, 
   PlotRange -> All];
g4 = ListPlot3D[Flatten[r4, 1], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.65]], Mesh -> False, 
   PlotRange -> All];
g5 = ListPlot3D[Flatten[r5, 1], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.65]], Mesh -> False, 
   PlotRange -> All];
g6 = ListPlot3D[Flatten[r6, 1], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Opacity[0.65]], Mesh -> False, 
   PlotRange -> All];
g7 = ListPlot3D[Flatten[r7, 1], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.65]], Mesh -> False, 
   PlotRange -> All];
g8 = ListPlot3D[Flatten[r8, 1], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Magenta, Opacity[0.65]], Mesh -> False, 
   PlotRange -> All];
ticks = {{-\[Pi], "-\[Pi]"}, {-\[Pi]/2, "-\[Pi]/2"}, {0, 
    "0"}, {\[Pi]/2, "\[Pi]/2"}, {\[Pi], "\[Pi]"}};
Plothermitain = 
 Show[g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 20}, 
  Frame -> True, Ticks -> {ticks, ticks, Automatic}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"y", "z", "E"}, ImageSize -> 250, 
  ImagePadding -> All]
```

In the $y-z$ plane, eigenvalues of my matrices exhibit some regions where two of the eigenvalues become zero and degenerate.
My question is how to obtain the region numerically and plot it in the 2D y-z plane.
[Previously](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269566/finding-zeros-of-an-equation), some suggestions for obtaining these results when the symbolic equations of eigenvalues are given. However, here I don't have access to any symbolic expression.

Comment: Please post the code about the 3D plot.

Comment: @cvgmt I have included the script in my question.

Comment: The determinant of a matrix is the product of the eigenvalues. So the det is zero exactly when one (or more) of the eigenvalues are zero. Using this idea, you can do: det = Numerator[Det[Rationalize[Atmp]] // FullSimplify]; this gives a fairly simple expression in terms of y and z. This constructs a symbolic expression for when the eigenvalues are zero.

Comment: @bills Thanks for your nice suggestion. I have tried ```det = Numerator[Det[Rationalize[Atmp]] // FullSimplify]
reSol = Reduce[{Re@det == 0, y \[Element] Reals, 
   z \[Element] Reals}, {y, z}]
RegionPlot@
 ImplicitRegion[reSol, {{y, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {z, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}}]``` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can rationalize the matrix and calculate its symbolic eigenvalues:

```
ev = Eigenvalues@Rationalize@Atmp;
```

We can then explore these eigenvalues to qualitatively seek the ones that go to zero and are degenerate as follows. Note that working with arbitrary precision seems necessary here to obtain accurate and complete contours:

```
ContourPlot[# == 0, {y, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 10] & /@ ev
```

[image: contours of the eight eigenvalues]

So eigenvalues (1 and 4), and (5 and 8) seem to be the ones of interest, in two degenerate pairs. Let's focus on those:

```
ContourPlot[
  ev[[{1, 5}]] == 0, {y, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi},
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Black] & /@ {"y", "z"}),
  FrameTicks -> {{Range[-Pi, Pi, Pi/2], None}, {Range[-Pi, Pi, Pi/2], None}},
  WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision, PlotPoints -> 20
]
```

[image: regions where eigenvalues are zero]

Comment: This is an excellent response! Thank you very much (+1).

Answer (score 3):

Following up on my comment, the determinant of a matrix is the product of the eigenvalues. So the det is zero exactly when one (or more) of the eigenvalues are zero. Using the ContourPlot from MarcoB's answer, then yields

```
p = Numerator[Det[Rationalize[Atmp]]//FullSimplify]; 
(ContourPlot[# == 0, {y, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}] & /@ p)[[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is very nice! Thank you for sharing that(+1).